# How to target HTML DOM elements from an external webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I have obtained the whole HTML of the webpage am getting repeated errors like `response.getElementById is not a function`

this is my code:

```
$.get('myUrl', function(response) {
  storageVariable = response.getElementById('#id').textContent;
  console.log(storageVariable);
})
```

What I exactly want to do is target the different elements of the external webpage, and store them in different variables.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is `response`? Please share a [mcve] of your code

Comment: It's likely that your response is a string not an actual DOM element.  You'll need to convert it first. David Walsh has a good article about how to do this: https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes

Comment: I referred to this article for this piece of code. [https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86). Response is the whole HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got the HTML as a String from an AJAX call, for example, you can use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) API and then use all `document` methods on this object:

```
$.get('myUrl', function(response) {
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
  console.log(parsedHtml.getElementById("<something>").innerHTML);
})
```